# How to bind a TextBlock to a RadioButton when checked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have three `RadioButton`s as shown.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="Rbtn_Dashboard" IsChecked="True" Height="40" Style="{StaticResource DashboardRBtnStyle}" Content="DASHBOARD" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"  FontSize="13"  GroupName="nav"   />
<RadioButton x:Name="Rbtn_AdminSettings"  Height="40" Visibility="{Binding AppSettings, Converter={StaticResource ConvertToVisible}}"  Style="{StaticResource DashboardRBtnStyle}" Content="ADMIN SETTINGS" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"  FontSize="13"   GroupName="nav"   />
<RadioButton x:Name="Rbtn_ManageUsers"  Height="40"  Visibility="{Binding ManageUsers, Converter={StaticResource ConvertToVisible}}" Style="{StaticResource DashboardRBtnStyle}" Content="MANAGE USERS" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"  FontSize="13"   GroupName="nav"   />
```

And I also have a `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtDescName" Text="(display previewed discriptions.)"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontSize="14" Foreground="#FF555555" Margin="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
```

My challenge now is:
when `x:Name="Rbtn_AdminSettings"` is checked, I want the Text in `x:Name="txtDescName"` to change from `DASHBOARD` to `APPSETTINGS`. Thanks.

Comment: use script if don't want to use code behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Trigger` or in your case three `Trigger` would do the job.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName= Rbtn_Dashboard, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text"
                            Value="DASHBOARD" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName= Rbtn_AdminSettings, Path=IsChecked}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text"
                            Value="APPSETTINGS" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName= Rbtn_ManageUsers, Path=IsChecked}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text"
                            Value="MANAGE" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Your welcome. Triggers are really cool and you can do alot of 'magic' with em.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtDescName" Text="{Binding ElementName=Rbtn_AdminSettings, Path=Content}"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontSize="14" Foreground="#FF555555" Margin="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
```

And similarly for the other 2 radio buttons as well. 
Although, Ideally you would have your radio buttons bound to a property in your view model and then your text block can be set from your VM depending which radio button was selected

Comment: How can i do that?